# Check for USB drive on Linux in Python?

Tags: python, linux, usb, dbus

I am trying to make a system in Python that checks if a file exists on a USB drive, and if no drive is present it waits for the dbus system to register a new device and then checks again.

I have the checking the mtab bit down. I have the checking if the file exists bit down. I have the dbus bit working, but what I'm struggling with at the moment is getting it to break out of the dbus bit when the drive is registered so I can check the mtab and then check the file.

I hope that made sense.

I will apologise for the poor coding style - I'm only just getting into it.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string, time, os, dbus, gobject, sys
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def device_added_callback(device):
  print ("Block device added. Check if it is partitioned")
  usbdev = "".join(device.split("/")[5:6])
  if usbdev.endswith("1") == 1:
    print ("Block device is partitioned. Waiting for it to be mounted.")
    # This is where I need to break out of the USB bit so I can check mtab and then check the file exits.

def waitforusb():
  DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
  bus = dbus.SystemBus()
  proxy = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
  iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, "org.freedesktop.UDisks")
  devices = iface.get_dbus_method('EnumerateDevices')()
  usbdev = iface.connect_to_signal('DeviceAdded', device_added_callback)
  mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
  mainloop.run()
  return usbdev

def checkusbispresent():
  f = open("/etc/mtab")
  lines = f.readlines()
  f.close()
  for line in lines:
    mtpt = "".join(line.split()[1:2])
    isthere = mtpt.find("media")
    if isthere == 1:
      return mtpt

def checkserialfile(mtpt):
  _serialfile=mtpt+"/serial.lic"
  if ( not os.path.isfile(_serialfile)):
    print("Error: serial file not found, please download it now")
  else:
    print("Serial file found, attempting validation... ")

usbdrive = checkusbispresent()
if ( usbdrive is not None ):
  checkserialfile(usbdrive)
else:
  print ("USB drive is not present. Please add it now.")
  added = waitforusb()
  print added
```

Comment: `mainloop.run()` is the line it's getting stuck on?

Comment: @CameronSparr it's not getting stuck in so much as it does not fail and exit. It gets stuck in so much as when waitforusb() gets called, it does what it's supposed to and device_added_callback(device) gets called correctly, the USB block device gets listed, the .join and .endswith work fine (so I can check whether the partition is registered... which is it), but then I can't figure out what to do next to get out of the dbus bit. I've tried various while True; break loops... to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem... is the print statement being executed? What do you mean by "break out"?

Comment: I think you could be right about it getting stuck in `mainloop.run()`, but my brain has turned to mush today and I can't figure out how to get it to wait for udev to return that a block device has been added (or to poll for it in a loop) and then continue with the checking mtab, checking for the file bit.

Comment: [link](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gobjectmainloop.html) says that I can use `mainloop.quit()` to kill it, but I'm not sure where to put it. If I put it after the `mainloop.run()`, it doesn't get executed; if I put it somewhere inside `def device_added_callback(device):` then I get an exception thrown because mainloop doesn't exist inside that def!

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

I very much doubt it is the most elegant solution, but I'll attack the elegance at some later stage.

I made mainloop global, and then I could access it from within device_added_callback:

```
def waitforusb():
  DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
  bus = dbus.SystemBus()
  proxy = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
  iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, "org.freedesktop.UDisks")
  devices = iface.get_dbus_method('EnumerateDevices')()
  iface.connect_to_signal('DeviceAdded', device_added_callback)
  global mainloop
  mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
  mainloop.run()

def device_added_callback(device):
  usbdev = "".join(device.split("/")[5:6])
  if usbdev.endswith("1") == 1:
    mainloop.quit()
```